# Deployment - apple app store icon appears incorrectly

Tags: ios, flash, deployment, itunes-app

After a long testing, my game has finished and ready to release. but when I deploy it as :Deployment - apple app store, as I drag it into itunes, the icon appear as the itunes default icon (although when I run the app on ipad, the icon appears correctly).

[image: icon]

This has never happened before when I did the testing with "quick publish for device testing", it run perfectly with my correct icon on itunes. Have anyone faced this problem before?

Comment: Did you include the `iTunesArtwork` image 512x512?

Comment: Yes, i include all the image required, it run ok on quick publish but not on deployment mode...